# Change working directory for gradle multi-module project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm a new Gradle user coming from Maven and I've hit a bit of a roadblock in our CI builds due to the issue with the working directory in a multi-module build.  Specifically it's the unit tests, as I have a few unit tests that are loading resources that are relative to the sub-project directory.

If I build the projects individually, everything works as expected.  If I build them using the master build.gradle file, then I run into issues with files not being found, etc.

So the question is,can I change the working directory when gradle forks a new Java process to build the sub-module?

TIA

Comment: Show your build files; both for maven and gradle

Comment: I'm running into this error too. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've the similar problem: shared config directory in root for Gradle muli-module, migrated from Maven. Manipulation with `projectDir` (https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-set-a-common-build-directory-for-multi-module-builds-in-the-root-project-directory/5570, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/fine_tuning_project_layout.html#sub:modifying_element_of_the_project_tree) is restricted in last Gradle version, so I've moved to defining root directory location environment variable or fixed place (e.g. `~` or `\..\..`) or JVM parameter with this location.